# Add to list by click on image\button

Tags: php, jquery, list

I have a few images on the screen and I want that each click will put the value of this image in a list. Then I need to send this list into sql table (so its need to be an array?)

any ideas?

```
<a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/bezeq.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/hot.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/mirs.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/013.png" alt="" /></a>
```

this is for example. each image i click i have a list in the side. and when i click on hot.png  its add to the list hot . and than i need to take this list and put it in sql table.

THIS IS THE WHOLE CODE

```
<div id="content" >

    <div class="socials" id="move" >
        <ul class="reset">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/bezeq.png" alt="1" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/hot.png" alt="2" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/mirs.png" alt="3" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/013.png" alt="4" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/012.png" alt="5" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/hotnet.png" alt="6" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/yes.png" alt="7" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/golantelecom.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/019mars.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/bezeqinter.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/hotmobile.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/aridor.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/triplecloud.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/rimon.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/youphone.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/orange.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/pelephone.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/cmp/rami.png" alt="" /></a></li>
        </ul>           
    </div>  


</div>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(){
        $('select').append('<option>'+$(this).find('img').attr('alt')+'</option>');
    });
});​
    </script>


      <select multiple="multiple"  ></select>​
```

Comment: Can you post some code? html, php...

Comment: What do you mean by the 'value' of this image?

Comment: 1. paste `img`; 2. paste hidden `input` in your form for each img; 3. bind action to change hidden input when clicking on image; 4. by `submit` all checked images going to server, where u insert them in DB; 5. profit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you have a `<select multiple="multiple"></select>` on the right to the image links, then use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(){
        $('select').append('<option>'+$(this).find('img').attr('src')+'</option>');
    });
});
```

What this does:

- On a click

  - Find the `img` tag inside the clicked `a`

    - Append the `src` attribute to the `select` input.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PKBXL/)

**Edit:**

Let's say you change this line:

```
$('select').append('<option>'+$(this).find('img').attr('src')+'</option>');
```

Into this:

```
$('select').append('<option selected="selected">'+$(this).find('img').attr('src')+'</option>');
```

So that all the options are selected (so that they get passed through the form values to PHP).

Then, on the PHP side, use something like this:

```
$images = $_POST['yourSelect'];
```

Then you can go through the array using a for:

```
foreach($images as $i){}
```

Comment: how i convert it to an array? becuase i need to put it in sql. every src\value\something else. into a table threw php.

Comment: I`m using this files jquery.js mobilyblocks.js init.js what i need to add more, what document that what you gave me will work.  thanks again

Comment: My example depends on jquery.js

Comment: what version? i need to add this? https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: i added the whole code now. and its not working. i`m using the 3 documents of jquery.